# Service layer bean validation in Spring 5?

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I need to validate beans given as argument to service layer methods in a Spring 5 application. I can get validation to work on controllers but on service layer the @Valid annotation is ignored. The service class is annotated with @Validated and an instance of it is autowired into the controller class thats making the method call.

I need to do this in a non-Boot application. I've found some instructions but they have been Boot-specific.

What am I missing here, why does this work on controller but not on the call from controller to service layer? Based on some googling, on controller level this might be somehow connected to the DispatcherServlet?

What do I need to do to make this work on service layer? The reason I want to do this on service layer is that we have validation on service layer in other apps (Jersey framework + older Spring) and others want consistency.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it works for `@Controller` class handler methods is that Spring uses a special `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` called `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` which performs **validation** before resolving the argument to use in your handler method.

The service layer, as we call it, is just a plain bean with no additional behavior.

You can explicitly use **SpringValidator**

```
@Bean
public SpringValidator<ClassToValidate> springValidator() {
        SpringValidator<ActivityCsvDTO> springValidator = new SpringValidator<>();
        springValidator.setValidator(localValidatorFactoryBean());
        return springValidator;
    }
```

and directelly call `validate()` method

```
    try {
     springValidator.validate(ObjectToValidate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return log.error("error validation", e);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So is there no way to make this work by configuration alone? I'd really like to avoid having to explicitely call anything. 

As I said, we have other applications, basically other endpoints of the same web app that run on a different servlet and that servlet is configured with Jersey Framework and Spring. Somehow validation works on that other servlet. The configuration with those frameworks is a bit complicated and the spring version is different so I'm not really sure if its Jersey that allows for validation to work or there's something in the configs that I'm missing.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I should be able to do service layer bean validation using MethodValidationPostProcessor. I tested it in a separate, simple Spring 5 project and it works. I needed LocalValidatorFactoryBean and MethodValidationPostProcessor beans and a validator like Hibernate validator in my pom.xml. And I needed to annotate the service class with @Validated. So I just need to dig deeper into the configs of the project I'm working on. As said, its a bit complicated since the same application has two servlets which run different frameworks. Anyway, thanks for your help!