# Java injection on parameter validation (without REST API call)

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a `class A` and I want to validate that the "`id`" is not more than 15 chars, so I am using  `@Size(min = 1, max = 15, message = "Error")`:

```
public final class A {

    @Size(min = 1, max = 15, message = "Error")
    private final String id;
    private final String anotherString;
  ....
}
```

And I am using `A` like this below, with `@Valid`:

```
  public final class C {
    
    void methodThatUsesA(@Valid final A a, final B b)  {
    ...
    }
  }
```

Moreover if I call `methodThatUsesA` like this below, with a string that have more than 15 chars, the validation is not triggered and I don't know why:

```
 methodThatUsesA(new A("AZERTYUIOPQSDFGDFG", 'a'), new B()){}
```

Any help is accepted :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Service layer bean validation in Spring 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63618897/service-layer-bean-validation-in-spring-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create and provide a `MethodValidationPostProcessor` Spring-managed bean as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class MethodValidationConfig {

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

And then you need to add `@Validated` to your class as follows:

```java
@Validated
public final class A {

    @Size(min = 1, max = 15, message = "Error")
    private final String id;
    private final String anotherString;
    
    ....
}
```

Keep in mind that this will only work if both `A` and `C` are Spring-managed beans.